# REST API search for resources where eg category is not set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I'm creating a restful API for an app with node.js and mongodb, where I have to deal with videos and categories.

Nearly every video is assigned to a category, but some of them are not. Now I don't know how to implement a query to list all videos without category in a restful way.

What about

GET /api/videos/?category=empty

Comment: If you want to keep the same pattern for videos with and without category, the way you suggested is fine. But I don't see any problem if you create a method exclusively to query videos without category like `GET /api/videos/uncategorized`. Another point: you might have a problem if someone creates a category named `empty`

Comment: Thanks, sound goods. I was thinking to complicated

Answer (score 0):

On **Mongoose** Try:

```
Video
.find({category: {$eq: null}})
.then( videos => {
// here all videos without category
});
```